# Rails 6 and rebuilding cached assets(?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pipeline, wicked-pdf

I have an app that supposed to generate PDFs with a gem called wicked_pdf. When I try to invoke it, I get an error. The logs give a hint of the problem:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (The asset "qr-code.js" is not present in the asset pipeline.
):
1: <%= javascript_pack_tag 'qrcode' %>
2: <%= wicked_pdf_javascript_include_tag "qr-code" %>
3:
4: <%=wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag 'pdf' %>
5: <p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

app/views/health_cards/show.pdf.erb:2
app/controllers/health_cards_controller.rb:21:in `block (2 levels) in show'
app/controllers/health_cards_controller.rb:12:in `show'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:31:in `handle_fhir_errors'
```

However, I noticed that there is a file the application's javascript directory at:

`./app/javascript/packs/qrcode.js`

so I changed the include statement at line 2 above from `qr-code` to `qrcode` but it doesn't make a difference. Given the parent directory is called "packs", it looks like it could be doing some fancy caching somewhere. How can I rebuild my assets and/or fix the issue?

Comment: Why are you adding those 2 link tags one for qrcode and one for qr-code? are you following some tutorial?

Comment: Inherited code. I'm not sure what those two link tags are literally saying.

Comment: I see the wicked_pdf_javascript_include_tag references a local file in your public folder https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/blob/2dc96dde2e0fd7362395064f2480cac1edcc1f48/lib/wicked_pdf/wicked_pdf_helper.rb#L27, make sure you have the `qr-code.js` there. Though I don't know why you have both, personally I would try to use just the first one if that works, and if not I'd copy the qrcode.js from the packs to public/javascripts as `qr-code.js`.